# Matlab: Polynomial Expansion Routine

Tags: matlab

In Mathematica, [it's easy to expand](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(x%5E3%2B4x%5E2%2B8x-7)%5E4) terms like

```
(ax^2+bx+c)^n
```

But is there anyway I can do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any arbitrary expression: not without the Symbolic Toolbox.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/expand.html

However, if you wish to expand polynomials, you can use the `conv` function. Just run it in a loop.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
n = 5;
soln = [a b c];
for i=1:n-1
   soln = conv(soln,[a b c]);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use my [sympoly](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9577-symbolic-polynomial-manipulation) toolbox.

```
>> sympoly a b c x
>> (a*x^2+b*x+c)^3
ans =
    c^3 + 3*b*c^2*x + 3*b^2*c*x^2 + b^3*x^3 + 3*a*c^2*x^2 + 6*a*b*c*x^3 + 3*a*b^2*x^4 + 3*a^2*c*x^4 + 3*a^2*b*x^5 + a^3*x^6
```

Comment: thanks! One thing I am not sure, though, is whether your toolbox is compilable to .Net.