# Polynomial expansion: Separating polynomial coefficients and x's

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, symbolic-math, binomial-coefficients

I want to automatically calculate expansions of polynomials where there are variables (x1,x2,...) as well as coefficients (c1,c2, ...). My goal is to calculate `p(1)*(c1*x1+c2*x2+...)^n+ ... + p(n)*(c1*x1+c2*x2+...)^n .`

As you can notice the resulting expression can be written as `F(x1,x2...)*g(c1,c2,...)` [where F is a row matrix and g is column matrix], i.e. there is some multiplicative decoupling between the coefficients and the variables.

Right now I use the MATLAB symbolic toolbox and construct F and g by manually examining the resulting symbolic expansions. This is not very feasible as if n is big and `c=(c1,c2,...)` is too big there are too many terms and it is no longer possible manually. For instance for `(c1*x1+c2*x2+c3)` and `n=2`, what I want is following.

```
>> p=[2 5]

p =

     2     5

>> syms c1 c2 c3
>> syms x1 x2
>> expression= p(1)*(c1*x1+c2*x2+c3)^2 + p(2)*(c1*x1+c2*x2+c3);
>> expand(expression)

ans =

2*c1^2*x1^2 + 4*c1*c2*x1*x2 + 4*c1*c3*x1 + 5*c1*x1 + 2*c2^2*x2^2 + 4*c2*c3*x2 + 5*c2*x2 + 2*c3^2 + 5*c3

>> F=[5*x1 5*x2 5 4*x1*x2 4*x1 4*x2 2*x1^2 2*x2^2 2]

F =

[ 5*x1, 5*x2, 5, 4*x1*x2, 4*x1, 4*x2, 2*x1^2, 2*x2^2, 2]

>> g=[c1 c2 c3 c1*c2 c1*c3 c2*c3 c1^2 c2^2 c3^2].'

g =

    c1
    c2
    c3
 c1*c2
 c1*c3
 c2*c3
  c1^2
  c2^2
  c3^2

>> expand(F*g)

ans =

2*c1^2*x1^2 + 4*c1*c2*x1*x2 + 4*c1*c3*x1 + 5*c1*x1 + 2*c2^2*x2^2 + 4*c2*c3*x2 + 5*c2*x2 + 2*c3^2 + 5*c3
```

I have found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766335/matlab-polynomial-expansion-routine) and it looks like there may be a way to do it automatically using `conv` etc. If one can come up with an automated solution (or at least some idea towards such automation) for the case where `x=(x1,x2) and c=(c1,c2,c3) and n=2`, the case depicted above; I guess I may be able to generalize it to higher dimensional cases.

Note: the ordering of terms in F or g does not matter, given that they are ordered in some structured way.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients from different terms don't overlap. The first term, `p(1)*(c'*x)^1`, has only terms of degree 1 in `xi` and `ci`, and so on. So it becomes a matter of computing the coefficients of one term at a time.

That, too, has a "simple" expression:

```
p(k)*(c'*x)^k = sum(i1,..,im>=0 with sum(i_)=k) 
    M(k;i1,..,im)*x1^i1*...*xm^im * c1^i1*...*cm^im
```

where the summation is such that the sum of all `i` equals `k`, and `M` is the [multinomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html).

For `m=3`, `n=2`, the `i`'s would be in the order of your example: `110,101,011,200,020,002`. M(2;110)=2 so the first term is `p(2)*M(2;110)*x1*x2 = 4*x1*x2'.

Your F and g terms are:

```
F(...) = p(k)*M(k;i1,..,im)*x1^i1*...*xm^im
g(...) = c1^i1*...*cm^im
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. For instance for my case powers in g is `[100,010,001,110,101,011,200,020,002]`. Is there nice way to generate this kind of vector as well. For any `m` and `n`.